# What are "if" and "this" in this function?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, remix, tokens, delegatecall

```
function() public {
  if(delegate.delegatecall(msg.data)) {
    this;
```

What are the requirements for "if" to execute "this" and what does "this" refer to in this function?

Comment: It's a weird example. Where did you find it?

Comment: It's a snippet of a solidity smart contract. I have updated the question to show the rest of the code.

Comment: In which version of solidity did you find this code?
`delegatecall` may return a boolean: true if the delegate call is successful.
`this` refer to the instance of the contract.
And this is a fallback function.