# What's mean Solidity instruction: "this;" alone?

Tags: solidity

I have this fragment of code from Ethernaut ([link](https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/level/0x68756ad5e1039e4f3b895cfaa16a3a79a5a73c59)):

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;
...
 function() public {
    if(delegate.delegatecall(msg.data)) {
      this;
    }
  }
```

What's means **this;** ?

Comment: Similar question [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/80015/what-are-if-and-this-in-this-function). Still with no answer

Comment: I think it has no meaning, but I might be wrong. I have seen people use it to avoid the `no-empty-blocks` solium warning: https://ethlint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#list-of-style-rules.

Comment: @Markus-soliditydeveloper.com If the block is necessary, I can understand that reason, but it doesn't seem like the `if` is needed for this example.  I believe it's just meant to demonstrate how a `delegatecall` to another contract is a security risk.

Comment: It's usually in order to prevent compiler warning about a `view` function which can be restricted to `pure`.

Answer (score 3):

It is typically in order to workaround compiler warning about a `view` function which can be restricted to `pure`, for example:

```
uint256[4] public arr;

constructor() public {
    arr[0] = 11;
    arr[1] = 22;
    arr[2] = 33;
    arr[3] = 44;
}

function func(uint256 x) public view returns (uint256) {
    if (x < arr.length)
        return handle(x, viewFunc);
    return handle(x, pureFunc);
}

function handle(uint256 x, function (uint256) view returns (uint256) func) internal view returns (uint256) {
    return func(x);
}

function viewFunc(uint256 x) internal view returns (uint256) {
    return arr[x];
}

function pureFunc(uint256 x) internal view returns (uint256) {
    this;
    return x * 2;
}
```

As you can see, function `handle` takes two input arguments:

1. `uint256 x`
2. `function (uint256) view returns (uint256) func`, which is a pointer to a `view` function

Now, suppose you wanted to call function `handle` and pass it a `pure` function. You could do this by declaring that `pure` function as `view`, but the compiler would issue a warning on that. So in order to revoke that warning, you simply add `this;` in the implementation of the `pure` function.

In your specific example, however, since the function is not even `view`, I am not so sure about the reason for adding `this;` in the implementation of this function. It obviously has no runtime impact.